# MediaElement.js Audio Player width breaking tables on Wordpress mobile theme

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have MediaElement.js activated on my Wordpress site, and I also have a mobile theme activated via Jetpack. I have the width on the media player set to 450, but it's breaking the tables on my mobile theme and distorting the website.

Also, I've found that the width function in the plugin settings does not effect the size of the player. It just seems to default to the width of the table in which it is contained.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How do I fix it? Haven't found any solutions through the plugin faq or support.